# Preventing execution until points are selected on matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent

I want to select 4 points on a `matplotlib` graph and operate on those points as soon as 4 four points are clicked on.
The code below will indeed store the 4 points in the variable `points` but does not wait for the four points to be selected. I tried adding a for loop and tried threading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799731/pausing-execution-until-interactive-point-selection-is-completed) but neither option worked. How can I solve this problem?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
image = np.load('path-to-file.npy')
tfig = ax.imshow(image)
points = []

def onclick(event):
    global points
    points.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

# this line will cause an error because the four points haven't been
# selected yet
firstPoint = points[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you might consider using `plt.ginput` instead of "rolling your own".

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(title='Select 4 points')

xy = plt.ginput(4)
x, y = zip(*xy)

ax.fill(x, y, color='lightblue')
ax.plot(x, y, ls='', mfc='red', marker='o')

plt.show()
```